# Gmail on ios browsers cannot center a table within a table

Tags: html, ios, gmail, center

We have run into a problem with emails accessed through gmail using browsers on iOS only recently. We have a call to action button that we would like to center on the email. We have previously been able to do this using a table within a table and an align=center, but now it just doesn't work.Here's an example of the code I'm talking about:

```
 <table width="551" height="51" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile-         content-size" style="min-width:551px;">
       <tr>
          <td height="51" style="text-align:center;" class="cta-one-row">
                    <!-- start button -->
                         <table border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="cta-show-them-table" style="color:#6a797b; text-decoration:none; background-color:#3b3b3b; border-radius:3px; width:230px;" height="50">
                             <tr>
                                  <td align="center" valign="middle" height="50" style="color:#FFFFFF;" class="cta-show-them"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="cta-show-them" style="color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:50px; height:50px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:-.5px; border:0;" title="Customize ">CALL TO ACTION</a>
</td>
                                    </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- end button -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

[Here's a link of what it looks like rendered on emailonacid.](http://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/viewresult/kFzS716H6O6T0d7lP2DBoYKN1dKwiPT712IqTPJWJX6c8#)

Has anyone else run into this sort of problem or have a fix? It's rather important that these buttons are centered!Thanks!